# Password_verify me regresa falso siempre

Tags: php, javascript

realizo un login pero la funcion password_verify siempre me regresa falso, he verificado la base de datos y parece estar bien el campo, hago print_r a la conntraseña de la base de datos y la ingresada y me muestra exactamente lo mismo pero aun asi me marca falso, que estoy haciendo mal?

```
    public function userLogin(){

            $data = $this->model->userLogin($_POST['email'],$_POST['password']);

            if (is_array($data)){
                echo json_encode($data);

            }
            else {
                echo $data;

            }
        }
```

```
function userLogin($email, $password){
    $where = "email = :email";
    $param = array("email" => $email);
    $response = $this->db->select1('*','usuarios',$where,$param);

    if (is_array($response)) {

        $response = $response['results'];

        if (password_verify($password,$response['password'])){

            $data = array(
            "IdUsuario" => $response['IdUsuario'],
            "nombre" => $response['nombre'],
            "apellido" => $response['apellido'],
            "roles" => $response['roles'],
            "imagen" => $response['imagen']

            );

            return $data;
        } else {
            $data = array(
            "IdUsuario" => 0
            );

            return $data;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ***hago print_r a la conntraseña de la base de datos y la ingresada y me muestra exactamente lo mismo***, eso indica que estás guardando la contraseña en *texto plano*, lo cual es una muy mala práctica. Además, la función [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) ***comprueba que el hash proporcionado (el que se almacena en la BD) coincida con la contraseña facilitada (por el usuario al hacer login)***. Por lo tanto si estás comparando dos cadenas exactamente iguales usando `password_verify()`, siempre te arrojará `false`. Saludos

Comment: Estaría bien que nos muestres el código de como creas el usuario, sobre todo como guardas la contraseña.